# Calling a web service from identity server validated application

Tags: tomcat, wso2, cxf

I have a web application developed in struts and web service developed in apache cxf. Both the applications are hosted in 2 different tomcat servers. Web application is user validation is implemented using WSO2 Identity manager. Its working fine I am getting a SAML Response from WSO2 Identity Manager. I want to call the web service from the first web app.

Now my questions are given below
1. How can I implement WS Security in WSO2 for the apache cxf web service hosted in tomcat
2. Can I pass the SAMLResponse recieved from WSO2IS to web application? If not what I need to pass

Please help me

Regards
Sreekumar

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Single-Sign-On pattern that places the webservice behind a WSO2 ESB as a proxy service?

I would suggest that you may find a complete solution available to you by placing the WS behind a WSO2 ESB and controlling access to the webservice through the ESB and IS bearer-policy configuration.

There is a good blog post on how to set that up here: http://suhothayan.blogspot.ca/2012/12/single-sign-on-across-web-applications_8.html

Let me know if that helps answer your question.